# Powershell Workflow Issue

Tags: powershell

Trying my hands on PS. Stuck with this issue. If i run the below code with first line, it errors out. However, if i don't have the first line, it works fine.

The code i am sending is a test code to re-produce the problem I have. I need to have first line of code in real program i am writing.

**Code Snippet**

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking
Function AddNumbers($i, $j)
{
   $i + $j

} 
workflow One 
{     
    Param
    (
        $i, $j
    )
    AddNumbers $i $j
}

clear
one 99 99999
```

**Error**

> Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'SQLSERVER' does not exist.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveNotFound
>       + PSComputerName        : [localhost]

Comment: SQLPS needs to be imported on an sql server or on a server that has the sql mgmt studio installed(SMO assemblies) so is either the case for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting double quotes around SQLPS

```
Import-Module "SQLPS" -DisableNameChecking
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, how ever that did not work. This is something related to profile. I even tried doing powershell -noprofile option, however even that is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I needed to put InlineScriptblock for Import-Module -SQLPS

```html
Function AddNumbers($i, $j)
{
   $i + $j

} 
workflow One 
{     
    Param
    (
        $i, $j
    )
    InlineScript{Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking}

    AddNumbers $i $j
}

clear
one 99 99999
```